# Symfony2 issue with % character in the link

Tags: php, symfony, routes

i have a bit of a weird problem with symfony2(2.4) with the % character in the url.

the url is:
/test/check/dq9L1oAOh2dDRLn3wmFW6wyHRfgCjRF%2FCelmCWOPIYeuLdO3dLuJ8In3LhFYZHzhCwwcqGWQFj1aPSAJUXaZ8e/

the routing is:

```
test_check:

    pattern:  /test/check/{id}/

    defaults: { _controller: TestSiteBundle:Test:Check}
```

if i remove the % character from the url it work, if i leave it in it returns a 404

i also added:

```
requirements:

    id: .+
```

and with the param it works however if the page will also contain GET params and if the url is to:

/test/check/dq9L1oAOh2dDRLn3wmFW6wyHRfgCjRF%2FCelmCWOPIYeuLdO3dLuJ8In3LhFYZHzhCwwcqGWQFj1aPSAJUXaZ8e/?val=true&test=yes

then the value of id will be dq9L1oAOh2dDRLn3wmFW6wyHRfgCjRF%2FCelmCWOPIYeuLdO3dLuJ8In3LhFYZHzhCwwcqGWQFj1aPSAJUXaZ8e/?val=true&test=yes

any ideeas for a best practice?

i know i could just leave the param in the routing and explode the string at / and have the good string within a array and since the string is urlencoded it will not generate a second / however i would like to apply a more pretty solution if there is one.

Thank you

Comment: I solved it by replacing the % before it goes in the link and after i get it in symfony but i`m still curious if someone knows a better way, i also tested out all the other chars and none cause this issue

Answer (score 0):

Requirements in the route definition accepts regular expression. So my suggestion is to build regexp filter in the route definition (a bit more sophisticated than .+)

If you expect to have up to one %2F (/ character) then you'd write your match something like that:

```
requirements:
    id: \w\/?\w*
```